# error 1084 in as3: expecting rightbrace before leftbracket

Tags: actionscript-3

cant find the error. needless to say that I am a newb. Any help would be highly apreciated

```
public function setDestination(param1:String, param2, param3:Boolean = true) : void
    {
        var _loc_4:* = {};
        {}[param1] = param2;      
        updateTo(_loc_4, param3);
        return;
    }// end function
```

Comment: Yeah, you get this kind of stuff decompiling other peoples' code.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is related to this line:

```
{}[param1] = param2;
```

Though I can't be sure of what was actually intended here, it may have been this:

```
_loc_4[param1] = param2;
```

Comment: @GerardoCampillo Sure - if this answer helped you may I suggest accepting it via the hollow tick to the left?